# Can't properly execute php file within bash file if in differenct directory

Tags: php, bash, ubuntu

So I have a a php script I'd like to run from a bash file script.sh. This is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/folder/file.php
```

The php file sends push notifications to an iOS app. The only way it works for me is if my current directory is /var/www/html/folder/ and the script is also in this 
directory. So if I cd .. and try to do

```
x@x:./folder/script.sh
```

I get an error from the php file saying "unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195(Unknown error)". I've also changed the permissions for both the php and bash file to rwx for all. Any ideas why it fails if everything isn't in the same directory?(Using Ubuntu)

Comment: try /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/folder/file.php

Comment: Thanks for the response but I get the same result with "x@x:/usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/folder/file.php

Comment: Is the php script using credentials/keys/etc. and assuming they will be found in the current directory? That's the most likely reason I imagine.

Comment: It is! So how do I deal with that? Include the absolute path to them within the php file?

Comment: Thank you Etan Reisner that was the issue.

Comment: Either that or find the file of the script file in the php script and use that as the path to the files.

Answer (score 0):

As Etan Reisner pointed out, my php file included credentials/keys referenced locally. Referencing them with absolute paths fixed the problem.